# C++ Program written in VS2012 won't work on Server 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I'm receiving the following error:

"The program can't start because mfc110u.dll is missing from your computer."

Has anyone else had this trouble?

Comment: This looks like a problem with deployment, did you install Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2012 on the target machine or shipped the needed files in any other way?

Comment: Yes, and I can see MFC110u.dll in C:\Windows\System32\

Comment: And you probably don't see the 32-bit version in c:\windows\syswow64

Comment: Nope, I don't see it in the syswow64 folder at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your application written with VS 2012 a x86 (32-bit) or x64 64-bit native application?

There are different [Visual C++ 2012 REDIST](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=255955) packages depending on if you are writing a x86 or x64 native app. You should make sure you are installing the correct one, or both.

Also be sure to set `_WIN32_WINNT` to 0x0600 if you are trying to target Windows Server 2008 (which is the same thing as Windows Vista). Windows Server 2008 R2 / Windows 7 would be 0x0601. See [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx).

Comment: It's written for win32

Comment: The "Win32" platform is x86 (32-bit). If you are on a Windows x64 edition, then you need to have ``MFC110u.dll `` in ``C:\Windows\SysWOW64``, which is installed by ``vcredist_x86.exe``.

Answer (score -1):

MSVCR110.dll is the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable dll that is needed for projects built with Visual Studio 2011. The dll letters spell this out.

MS = Microsoft, V = Visual, C = C++, R = Redistributable.

Download it and put in on your path.

Comment: It's already in C:\Windows\system32  and I've verified that this folder is in %PATH%